# how to update attributes from old version to new version using core data in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data-migration

i want to add two new attributes in my current database..when i update that database and click on "Add model version" it automatically converted into new version and creates new updated database..how that version works..and what kind of version it takes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should click "Add model version" before you make any change.
After your new version of db has created, you can add your new attributes into your NEW model version.

"NEVER" edit your old model version especially after you have submitted the version to App Store, otherwise the CoreData will NOT be able to update user's old database to your new version automatically.

Comment: The reason is because when we install app on user's device we are just replacing app file and our core data files will not be replaced ... this is the reason we use migration of coredata. For replacing database user manually have to delete the app and again have to install it...